# Cannot implicity convert type for parent control name

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a code for get the parent name of a `ContexMenu`, in particular when a user click in the `MenuItem` of the `ContextMenu` happean this:

```
DataGrid -> ContextMenu (MenuItem 1 was clicked) -> function through code is started -> function return the name of the DataGrid.

private void ClearTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Try to cast the sender to a Control
     Control ctrl = sender as Control;
     if (ctrl != null)
     {
          // Get the control name
          string name = ctrl.Name;

          // Get parent control name
          Control parent = ctrl.Parent;
          string parentName = parent.Name;
     }
}
```

But in `ctrl.Parent` I get this error:

> Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject "in" System.Windows.Controls.Control ". An explicit conversion exists, are you missing a cast?

What  I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a cast, in fact it's not needed to cast to `Control`, use the base class `FrameworkElement` instead:

```
 FrameworkElement parent = (FrameworkElement)ctrl.Parent;
 string parentName = parent.Name;
```

Comment: Yeah now working! A little question: with this code I get the name of the ContextMenu, but if I want get the name of the DataGrid where the ContextMenu was called?

Comment: Please post another question with the code of the context menu, it's otherwise hard to tell what the solution might be